# What is the best or fast way to add a star on top of a helmet?

Tags: modeling

To make it simpler, think helmet is a sphere.

Now I need to place a star or any other complex object you can think of - on it. It's a big star, and it looks like taking the half of the helmet - so it should be spherically bent too. It can be separate object.

(P.S. I watched another tutorial where the guy used boolean modifier in order to intersect two objects. The booleans seem to work on simple object. It didn't work in my case.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you use a [shinkwrap modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier), as well as a [solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) to give it some thickness, and possibly a [bevel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/bevel.html#bevel-modifier):

[image: Shape on surface]

This applies to any shape you'd like to project onto any surface.

Just keep in mind that you need to have enough geometry to allow it to deform smoothly, and preferably a quad loop around the border to avoid shading (or bevel) artefacts:

[image: Star geometry]

Answer (score 5):

Starting with a sphere and a star as separate objects, align the view so that the view is straight on to the star (in the second image I used *front view*).
[image: sphere and star]
[image: front view]
Select the star then the sphere, enter edit mode. Look oven on the [*tool shelf*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/introduction.html#tool-shelf) and press the [*Knife Project*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/knife_subdivide.html?#knife-project) button. This is what you will get.
[image: final result]

Comment: Thanks David, this helps a lot. Found this answer useful as the one I marked as an answer (because it was before)